# What happens to the run mode specific configuration, when I change that OSGi configuration through web console?

Tags: aem, sling

I have a configuration, which has different property values for different run modes of my AEM. And, I have multiple sling:OsgiConfig under different folders in my CRX repository, like `config.author`, `config.publish`. So if I want to change that configuration through the web console, I can see only one configuration, so, if I am changing that configuration, how will i be able to know that I changed which run mode specific configuration file?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, thus only as a comment: AFAIK you don't change these configuration files in CRX at all, but only the actual configurations you find in: crx-quickstart/launchpad/config. Thus no run mode specifics can be found.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz, can you help out here?

Comment: @Thomas , I think we can definitely change the OSGi configuration settings from the web console as well as from the CRX.

Comment: yes, you can change them, but you don't change the configuration nodes in CRX. They are parsed when you install a package containing them and then they are not touched until you change them with CRX DE Lite or another package.

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas wrote, the changes you do in WebConsole are not applied to existing `sling:OsgiConfig` nodes in CRXDE, instead, they are written into separate text files. These configurations are not run mode specific.

It means, that they will be applied under any run mode you start your AEM instance, until there will be config for this component under `/libs` or `/apps` (which have higher priority).

More on this topic, you can find [there](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#Configuration%20Persistence).

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from various links on web, is that-

I changed the configuration A from the webconsole-

1. That configuration A is **NOT** already present in the repository ----
        a new `sling:OsgiConfig` is created in the repository inside the /apps/{somewhere} and generelly this `{somewhere}` is `/system/config`
2. The configuration A already present in the repository--- then, suppose the configuration came from `/libs/foo/foundation/config` then, your configs are saved in the folder `/apps/foo/foundation/config` or gets overwritten in the same location
3. if the settings are changed by the admin, then, the configurations are saved in `*.config` file inside `/crx-quickstart/launchpad/config`

> And, the configuration settings changed through web console are applied to the current run mode,
>   irrespective of the current run mode, or the location of the config settings.